# Unable to convert PCL file to PDF using Filestream and PDFSharp

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, pdfsharp

I was unable to find a free library which can directly convert PCL file to PDF file, i had a thought of reading the PCL file into FileStream and saving it to a PDF document using PDF Sharp.

I tried the following code, but it gives me a blank PDF Document.

Can someone let me know what or where i'm doing it incorrectly?

```
 private void pdfSharpPclToPDF(string localPCLPath)
        {
            
            using(FileStream fleStream = new FileStream(localPCLPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (PdfDocument newPDF = new PdfDocument(fleStream))
                {
                    PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage(newPDF);
                    newPDF.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
                    newPDF.Save("D:\\Research\\PDF_Files\\output.pdf");
                }
            }
                    
        }
```

It would also help if someone could suggest any other open source library that can do the job for me.

Comment: It appears that the PCL file stores it's data in a [PCD binary format](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.html), which should be rather simple to implement. You may want to consider implementing and/or using some library that can rasterize the PCL first before attempting to write it to a PDF

Comment: Download a tool [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pcltopdf.html). It converts PCL to PDF. There are instructions as well.

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not use the filestream you create. If you invoke `Save()` without filename, PDFsharp will save the PDF document to the stream. If you invoke `Save(<filename>)` the document will be saved in that file.

PDFsharp cannot read PCL files. You are trying something that cannot work with PDFsharp.

Answer (score 0):

Most Applications will usually include some way to export content as a printer output. The higher end various output formats are generically referred to as PDL (Page Description Language) and historically were stored as filename.prn without distinguishing content.

The contents of a PRN could traditionally be Esc code as used by Epson , PostScript Programs or PCL (Printer Control Language) plus many others and nowadays we often include the formerly dumber PDF which is accepted by high end printers.

So PDFsharp can Export to PCL via a driver but is not designed to Import it for conversion into PDF output.

One application that can convert bidirectionally between PDL devices is Artifex GhostPDL (it does NOT Import Epson Esc Code but can export Epson code). GhostScript is Open Source, as you request, but is (AGPL) commercial licensed. However it is the most capable with a few decades of history.